# Redux double dispatch of action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm having some troubles on how I must dispatch 2 actions within the same function :

Initial function :

```
export function updateItem(item){
        return function (dispatch, getState) {
           let items = getState().ItemReducer.items;
            if(item.id_type === 519){
                deleteItem(items[0]);
            }
            return dispatch({
                type:"UPDATE_ITEM",
                item: item
            });
        };
}
```

The second action I must call :

```
export function deleteItem(item){
    return (dispatch) => {
        deleteItemApi(item);
        dispatch({
            type: "DELETE_ITEM",
            item: item
        })
    }
}
```

This function is used somewhere else and working fine but I don't know how to use it since I have already a `return function (dispatch, getState)`

Thanks  you!

Answer (score 3):

Since the function deleteItem returns a function you can dispatch it by calling:

```
deleteItem(items[0])(dispatch)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already using redux-thunk (action creators can return actions **OR a function**), thus you can just do this, dispatching an action creator that returns a function which returns an action:

```
export function updateItem(item){
        return function (dispatch, getState) {
           let items = getState().ItemReducer.items;
            if(item.id_type === 519){
                dispatch(deleteItem(items[0]));   //  <----------
            }
            return dispatch({
                type:"UPDATE_ITEM",
                item: item
            });
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a middleware and listen on action type UPDATE_ITEM then dispatch your DELETE_ITEM